# Error with ADODB Conn and Recordsets

Tags: vb.net, adodb, recordset

I am getting this error: "
Cannot change the ActiveConnection property of a Recordset object which has a Command object as its source." when tring to open a record set. One thing I should note: This procedure worked when it was written as inline SQL, but was removed for obvious reasons.

I have read that setting 'nocount on' on the stored procedure I was using would remedy this, but it did not. So, hopefully you folks can help me out.

Here is the connection getting initialized:

```
Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection
sConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnString").ConnectionString()
    objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConn.ConnectionString = sConn
    objConn.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseServer
    objConn.Open(sConn)
```

Then:

```
cmd = New ADODB.Command()
cmd.ActiveConnection = objConn

cmd.CommandText = "someProc"
cmd.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc
cmd.NamedParameters = True

cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("SomeID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 20, params("SomeID")))

objRec = New ADODB.Recordset()
objRec.Open(cmd, objConn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
```

Anyone experience this before? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used ADO in quite a while (certainly never in .NET), so this is a guess, but from [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `Open`:

> If you pass a Command object in the Source argument and also pass an
>   ActiveConnection argument, an error occurs. The ActiveConnection
>   property of the Command object must already be set to a valid
>   Connection object or connection string.

So, it sounds like your issue is that you are passing a connection into the `objRec.Open` call.  Since that parameter is optional, try not passing it.  I'm not sure if you pass `Nothing` or just omit the parameter, so try:

```
objRec.Open(cmd, , ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
```

And if it doesn't like that, try:

```
objRec.Open(cmd, Nothing, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
```

Comment: You are a champion. Thank you. I haven't solved the whole problem yet, but I have at least moved past this piece.